# Is it possible to remove variables from memory at runtime in visual studio?

Tags: variables, memory

Is it possible to debug remove data location from memory? and not just edit it

for example i have an object, and i would like to remove an attribute from it, so when it checks for the value, not the value should be null, but the variable shouldn't exist at all

Comment: What language are you talking about?

Comment: Which language? I don't know about C#, but in VC++, it is not possible. You can only make the memory containing invalid data, you can't "remove" a memory location!!!!

Comment: sorry, it's asp.net in vb. And i meant a pointer, i know the memory is always there, but variables are pointers to memory locations, and that's what i actually wanted to remove

Answer (score 1):

No. Simply speaking, memory is just a sequence of bytes, which is always there. Each byte has one of 256 values. None of these values mean "not in use".

Whether a given location in memory contains a variable is actually stored elsewhere (pointer). Often, this is even implicit. It's also possible that there are multiple places in memory where this information is duplicated. (Memory manager, multiple pointers, ...)